# Leaflet.Draw save coordinates

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I'd like to save the polyline coordinates. I'm creating it with Leaflet.Draw. The problem is that the coordinates are stored twice.

49.907018,16.324997,49.907018,16.324997,49.818936,16.340103,49.818936,16.340103....

this is my code

```
map.on('draw:created', function(p) {
   map.addLayer(p.layer);
    var points = p.layer.getLatLngs();
  puncte1=points.join(',');
  puncte1=puncte1.toString();
  puncte1=points.join(',').match(/([\d\.]+)/g).join(',');
           document.getElementById('coordinates').value=puncte1 ;

});
```

Answer (score 2):

First, this is not really GIS question but pure JS one. And second, personally I don't like regexp very much, since I have no idea what they do when I look at them, and the same goes for the one above.

Anyway, this (primitive) and veary easy to read code works:

```
var points = event.layer.getLatLngs();
var puncte1 = points.join(',');
puncte1 = puncte1.split('LatLng(').join('');
puncte1 = puncte1.split(')').join('');
puncte1 = puncte1.split(' ').join('');
```

If the question was about the regexp, then this is not the right answer. If question was about the solution, then it is.